# SIngle and Double click events not working as expected in canvas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas, mouseevent

I have a `Canvas` which is present in a `UserControl`, I have attached the `DoubleClick` event to this `UserControl` like this

```
mainWindow.CanvasLayout.MouseDoubleClick += 
new MouseButtonEventHandler(CanvasLayout_MouseDoubleClick);
```

I am using this event handler to achieve full screen functionality.

Now, `Canvas` can have various controls placed inside it. Drag and drop functionality is implemented for these controls similar to [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfDragAndDropSmorgasbord.aspx) codeproject article.

Basically, I handle these events for a control -

```
this._dragSource.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown +=
new MouseButtonEventHandler(DragSource_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);

this._dragSource.PreviewMouseMove += 
new System.Windows.Input.MouseEventHandler(DragSource_PreviewMouseMove);

this._dragSource.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += 
new MouseButtonEventHandler(DragSource_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp);
```

Now, when user `DoubleClicks` on a control(present in `canvas`) both `DoubleClick`(Full Screen) and single `Click`(drag & drop) operations are performed, i.e. if user double clicks on control and change its mouse position quickly, control position is changed(its dragged and dropped to new position).

Is there any way I can prevent drag and drop operation when user double clicks on a control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it, Instead of handling `MouseDoubleClick` event, I used `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` -

```
mainWindow.CanvasLayout.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown 
+= new MouseButtonEventHandler(CanvasLayout_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown);
```

and

```
void CanvasLayout_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object s, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ClickCount > 1)
    {
        // Do double-click code  
        // Code for FullScreen 
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just saved my butt on a Drag/Drop problem using one of the WPF MVVM Drag/Drop Behaviors on the net.  Great solution!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is, on mouse up start a timer the time should be retrieved from [`SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.doubleclicktime.aspx), and do the click action on the timer tick (only if you didn't detect the double click in the mean time, obviously).

Likewise use [`SystemInformation.DragSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.dragsize.aspx) to prevent accidental drag&drop.

Note, the `SystemInformation` class is part of WinForms so you need to add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`, this class will work just fine in WPF apps.

Comment: Thanks Nir, I was planning to try the timer but was able to solve the problem without it.